# Keying Hashes/Login Security?

Tags: security, encryption, hash, authentication

I am going to use hashing function, with salt:

$stored_pass = md5(md5($salt).md5($plain_pass)); **

/// I am wanting to know an efficient way to key/authenticate that hash.
I read up a bit about keying hashes, and MAC's, but didn't quite grasp HMAC's; so just figured that wrapping the hash in an encryption function, like aes, would work. ///

EG
$stored_pass = aes(md5(md5($salt).md5($plain_pass))); **

I would like to know the following:

Why key hashes for login? (Examples would be nice)

Methods for keying hashes? (Specifically for use in loign)

Disadvantages?

Are there still ways our hashing/password validation system could be more secure? (After we factor in hash, salted, keyed)

** What is the most "secure hashing algorithm?

" Secure by hardest to crack.

/// I read that sha-512 was one of the most secure; but then read contradicting articles stating, sha in any form should not be used, and something like bcrypt/scrypt should be used or PBKDF2. Then I read that bcrypt shouldn't be used, and has limitations. So I'm a bit confused. ///

When providing hash algorithms, I'd like to know the following:

- What are the limitations of the hash algorithm?
- Upsides?
- Downsides?

/// My main concern is user security, so if that means less 'speed' I'm not bothered. In my eyes the login function's purpose is user security, so reducing the credibility of that security for a few milliseconds seems silly to me. (Just personal opinion). ///

Also I'd appreciate comments on my function:

$stored_pass = aes(md5(md5($salt).md5($plain_pass))); **

And any alternatives would be appreciated.

Note: I know some suggest using some sort of api for this, with functions already written, but that's not really what I'm looking for. I'd prefer to learn more about it myself.

Comment: You might be interested in this writeup http://security.stackexchange.com/a/6415

Answer (score 1):

> I am going to use hashing function, with salt:
>
> ```
> $stored_pass = md5(md5($salt).md5($plain_pass));
> ```

Don't use MD5. [Learn how to safely store passwords](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/02/how-safely-store-password-in-2016) instead. That page might very well answer all of your questions.

> /// I am wanting to know an efficient way to key/authenticate that hash.
>   I read up a bit about keying hashes, and MAC's, but didn't quite grasp HMAC's; so just figured that wrapping the hash in an encryption function, like aes, would work. ///

MACs aren't the proper tool for the job here either, even if it seems tempting to use them. Maybe [this primer on cryptography concepts](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/08/you-wouldnt-base64-a-password-cryptography-decoded) will help illuminate the difference, but basically:

- MAC - Provide tamper-resistance for a message.
- Password hash - Slow, salted hashing algorithm.

They're totally different use-cases. (Although, PBKDF2 uses a MAC algorithm internally, so I can understand if you were confused by that.)

Encrypting a hash isn't what a MAC does, either. HMAC in particular is basically:

1. Hash your message (with a minor transformation).
2. Hash the key and output of step 1 (with another minor transformation).

> /// I read that sha-512 was one of the most secure; but then read contradicting articles stating, sha in any form should not be used, and something like bcrypt/scrypt should be used or PBKDF2. Then I read that bcrypt shouldn't be used, and has limitations. So I'm a bit confused. ///

Easy answer:

1. Use [`password_hash()`](https://secure.php.net/password_hash) to create password hashes.
2. Use [`password_verify()`](https://secure.php.net/password_verify) to authenticate passwords against hashes.
3. Stop worrying about it.

The limitations of bcrypt (truncating after 72 characters OR the first `NUL` byte -- which are mentioned in the first article I linked to) aren't a practical concern, and **[rolling your own crypto](http://www.cryptofails.com/post/75204435608/write-crypto-code-dont-publish-it) is definitely less secure than using bcrypt**.

If you are absolutely concerned about the bcrypt limitations, do this:

```
function bcrypt_sha384_hash($password, $cost = 10)
{
    $fasthash = base64_encode(
        hash('sha384', $password, true)
    );
    return password_hash($fasthash, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost' => $cost]);
}

function bcrypt_sha384_verify($password, $storedHash)
{
    $fasthash = base64_encode(
        hash('sha384', $password, true)
    );
    return password_verify($fasthash, $storedHash);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for some of the info, MD5 was an example btw.